# Powershell - How to invoke a checkbox windows with multiple choice

Tags: powershell, checkbox, powershell-2.0

I've seach some way to invoke a windows with many checkbox. Depending on the checkbox checked, that will enable or disable so part of my script.

I don't have any idea how to create the shape and how to set a "true/false" value in var to enable or disable portion of my script.

Anyone know how to create that kind of windows checkbox ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code ( made with the help of [PrimalScript](http://www.sapien.com/auth) for building form code ) has 3 checkbox. Based on the status (checked or not) the listbox will be populated from the result of some commands.
Copy, paste and play with it.

```
function GenerateForm {

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$checkBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$b1= $false
$b2= $false
$b3= $false

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------

$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    $listBox1.Items.Clear();    

    if ($checkBox1.Checked)     {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 1 is checked"  ) }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 2 is checked"  ) }

    if ($checkBox3.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 3 is checked"  ) }

    if ( !$checkBox1.Checked -and !$checkBox2.Checked -and !$checkBox3.Checked ) {   $listBox1.Items.Add("No CheckBox selected....")} 
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "Primal Form"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 450
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 236
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$button1.TabIndex = 4
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button1.Text = "Run Script"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 156
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button1.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

$listBox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 301
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 212
$listBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$listBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$listBox1.Name = "listBox1"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 137
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13
$listBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$listBox1.TabIndex = 3

$form1.Controls.Add($listBox1)


$checkBox3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox3.TabIndex = 2
$checkBox3.Text = "CheckBox 3"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 75
$checkBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox3.Name = "checkBox3"

$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox3)


$checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox2.TabIndex = 1
$checkBox2.Text = "CheckBox 2"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 44
$checkBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2"

$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox2)



    $checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
    $checkBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $checkBox1.TabIndex = 0
    $checkBox1.Text = "CheckBox 1"
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13
    $checkBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $checkBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1"

$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox1)


#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Comment: Wow, That's nice. I just ran the script. I will change the value and use it. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This is awesome!!! Can you revise this to take an array? I have a script that finds possible PC names based on the username and lists the matches. It would be nice to have this form to allow me to pick one of the results in the list as the correct PC to move into the right container and install the software.

Comment: @BradleySmith Post a new question and detail your problems,  someone will help you.  Thanks