# How do I combine multiple variables in an If statement?

Tags: powershell

So I am working on a simple user interface in PowerShell. VERY similar to this post:
[Powershell - How to invoke a checkbox windows with multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527832/powershell-how-to-invoke-a-checkbox-windows-with-multiple-choice)

Problem is, I have many more selections to choose from than just 3. For example let's say I have 10. This is my current issue code:

Note lines 43-68.

https://gist.github.com/preciselyprecise/89a202f928b2e70ea925439f61db9e56

I would like to do something similar to the commented block of code on lines 29-42. Problem is I am not sure how to combine the variable $i in the FOR loop with the $checkBox# variable. Another possible option I am seeing is maybe I could combine a string "checkBox" and simply concatenate $i to the end; problem being I don't know how to make the FOR loop interpret that solution as one conditional instead of say, a string.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Please keep in mind that I am new to powershell and StackOverflow so if I broke a rule or did something wrong please kindly say so :).

Comment: Just wanted to say, this is the difficult way of doing this I guess. For future reference, an easier way can be found here: https://foxdeploy.com/resources/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/. I think I will stick to manual way for now as this is more of learning experience for me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like the code you have commented would work if you took out the `$s` variable.

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 11; $i++) {
    $v = Get-Variable -Name "checkBox$i" -valueonly
    if ($v.Checked) {
        $listBox1.Items.add("Checkbox $i is checked")
    }
    else {
        echo Question
    }
}
```

However, I might suggest storing the checkboxes in an array instead of numbered variables. Something like this:

```
#make the array
$checkboxes = @()
1..11 | % { 
  $checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
  $checkboxes.Name = "CheckBox$_"
}

#and then get the values
foreach($checkbox in $checkboxes)
{
  if($checkbox.Checked)
  {
    $listBox1.Items.add("$($checkbox.Name) is checked")
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot for the quick response. I think I will wait to see if others answer with a simply better way before I choose the "correct" answer though.