# Creating a powershell GUI that calls seperate powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, server, installation

Can someone point me in the right direction? I want to create a powershell script that opens up to a module with check boxes and fields.

Say I have individual powershell scripts that I want to run on a server. I want to be able to have them all in the window and be able to toggle them on and off (with a checkbox) as needed. Here is an example of some code and the GUI I want to make.

So each check box would add the respective code to the list to run. I should be able to get the GUI setup. Its the run button, getting the checkbox to call up a script and the variable field I'm not too sure about.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3zga.jpg)

Here is the code I am working with

```
#This creates the form and sets its size and position
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Server Setup / Install Roles"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,800) 

#This creates a checkbox called Set Remote Execution to: unrestricted
$objSet_RECheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objSet_RECheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
$objSet_RECheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$objSet_RECheckbox.Text = "Set Remote Execution to: unrestricted"
$objSet_RECheckbox.TabIndex = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objSet_RECheckbox)

#This creates a checkbox called Change time zone
$objTimeCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objTimeCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,30) 
$objTimeCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$objTimeCheckbox.Text = "Change time zone"
$objTimeCheckbox.TabIndex = 2
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTimeCheckbox)

#This creates a checkbox called Install DNS Role
$objDNSCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objDNSCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) 
$objDNSCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$objDNSCheckbox.Text = "Install DNS Role"
$objDNSCheckbox.TabIndex = 3
$objForm.Controls.Add($objDNSCheckbox)

#This creates a checkbox called Install DHCP Role
$objDHCPCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objDHCPCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,70) 
$objDHCPCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$objDHCPCheckbox.Text = "Install DHCP Role"
$objDHCPCheckbox.TabIndex = 4
$objForm.Controls.Add($objDHCPCheckbox)

#This creates a checkbox called Install Print Role
$objPrintCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objPrintCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,90) 
$objPrintCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$objPrintCheckbox.Text = "Install Print Role"
$objPrintCheckbox.TabIndex = 5
$objForm.Controls.Add($objPrintCheckbox)

#This creates a checkbox called Install AD and DC promo
$objAD_NewCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objAD_NewCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,110) 
$objAD_NewCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$objAD_NewCheckbox.Text = "Install AD and DC promo"
$objAD_NewCheckbox.TabIndex = 6
$objForm.Controls.Add($objAD_NewCheckbox)

#This creates a label for the DomainMode TextBox1
$objLabel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,140) 
$objLabel1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel1.Text = "Domain Mode"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel1) 

#This creates the DomainMode TextBox1
$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,160) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$objTextBox1.TabIndex = 0 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)

#This creates the RUN button and sets the event
$RUNButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$RUNButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,190)
$RUNButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$RUNButton.Text = "RUN"
$RUNButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$RUNButton.TabIndex = 9
$objForm.Controls.Add($RUNButton)


$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: This is kind of close to what I'm trying to achieve.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527832/powershell-how-to-invoke-a-checkbox-windows-with-multiple-choice

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered all your questions there.

In the other code you are referring to, the button has an event handler. Whatever is inside this code block, gets executed when you press the button.

Inside the code block, the code is looking for which checkbox has been checked using the `if` loop. All you need to do is call the script you want from the correct `if` loop. Instead of external script files, you could also call `scriptblocks` which I think is a cleaner way.

```
$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    $listBox1.Items.Clear();    

    if ($checkBox1.Checked)    {  "C:\MyScript\Script1.ps1" }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    {  "C:\MyScript\Script2.ps1" }

    if ($checkBox3.Checked)    {  "C:\MyScript\Script3.ps1" }
}
```

If you want to do more with the results of the script after execution, you can put that too inside the `if` block.

I have written one in GUI that uses checkboxes if you want to refer: [Windows Patching Assistant](https://github.com/RohinSidharth/Windows-Patching-Assistant)

Comment: I have added the code I want to use in the original post. This method you posted, how would I implement it to call each powershell script? I will look at your script also to see how it works. TY.

Comment: What i have posted is the event handler of the "run" button. In your code, you have only created the "Run" button. You will need to create an event handler for your "run" button and use this method inside it. if you look closely, based on the boxes checked, I am calling 3 different ps1 script files. You can create an event handler from the GUI building tool you are using.

Comment: If you are referring my code, look at line 1354. You will see an button click event handler, `$buttonStartJob_Click` followed by a body. Whatever you need to happen when you click the button, goes in here. In your case, it would be what I posted above, i.e, the code to verify checkbox and call the appropriate external script file.

Comment: OK, the more I'm looking at this is there a way to append it to one powershell script. I want to run a log on the whole thing instead of each script. I have about 30 total check marks I need to add. Thanks for you input, I will look at this more later.

Comment: Well sure. But to differentiate between different checkbox item actions, you will need to use something like a `switch` statement. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx