# Hide Checkbox of Parent/Specific Node in Treeview

Tags: powershell, treeview

so i have a Form with a Treeview and i want it too look like this
(I stole this Picture from another Post
[image]

I googled and found nothing for Powershell but C# so i tried to adopt it but i am just not good enough.

[here the Post i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698369/how-to-disable-a-winforms-treeview-node-checkbox)

what i have so fare is as follows

```
$tvCRSC_DrawNode=[System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler]{

if ($_.Node.Level -eq 1)
{
    $_.DrawDefault = $true
}
else
{
    $Format = [System.Drawing.StringFormat]::GenericDefault
    $Brush = New-Object Drawing.SolidBrush([System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255))
    $_.Graphics.DrawString($_.Node.Text,$_.Node.TreeView.Font,$Brush, $_.Node.Bounds.X, $_.Node.Bounds.Y, $Format)
}
}
```

But with that i get a treeview where the Node where i want no Checkpoint is just blank

- Blank

  - [CB]ChildNode
  - [CB]ChildNode
- Blank

  - [CB]ChildNode

as for the link.. i do not realy understand why they hide the Checkbox for the level 1 node or why there is a function needed at all..

I just want to draw the Level 0 Node myself without a CB but all i get is the Blank.
Maybe someone can help me to understand and adopt the C# to Powershell.

Best Regards

Comment: maybe adapt the answer here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527832/powershell-how-to-invoke-a-checkbox-windows-with-multiple-choice

Comment: as far as i have seen this does not use a treeview. It just uses Checkboxes... i'll look deeper into this. But i don't think that this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you just do not look far enough.
The Answer was in the Post i linked in the Question. [Right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60933785/12414735)

i just had to edit it in the Function...
had to replace any [Marshal] into [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]

it now works like a charm.